# Use uart on Raspberry Pi usb port with Python

Tags: python, linux, mono, uart

im working on a project to connect a Pic to a Raspberry pi via uart.

I know they both have uart pins, but I need to connect them via usb, the cable also serves as the power supply for the Pic.

So my question is, is it possible to use python, C# might also be an option with mono, to use an USB port on the Raspberry Pi for UART?

[this is a tutorial I found about uart on the Raspberry Pi with Python](http://www.elinux.org/Serial_port_programming)

[a turorial on what is uart](https://electrosome.com/uart-raspberry-pi-python/)

Comment: Why do you NEED to connect them via usb if there is already dedicated uart pins ?

Comment: Could also use an FTDI (or similar) USB -to- Serial converter chip.

Comment: Get a PIC with USB controller... there are plenty of them

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

USB uses two 'pins' for transmission using 'differential signaling'.
This means, both pins are used for sending and transmission.

In UART you use one pin for transmission and one for reception.

Without any interface, not possible.